# Block Auto-Forwarding in Office 365

Tags: microsoft-office-365

I am trying to disable the ability of users with email accounts on a specific domain from forwarding their email.  I have tried following these instructions:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mitchelatmicrosoft/2015/05/03/exchange-online-blocking-auto-forward-messages-to-external-recipients/

However, I cannot seem to get this to work.  Even when I just have a single parameter of "The message type is...Auto-Forward", the forwarded messages are still allowed through.

What am I missing?

Comment: Auto-forwarded messages are different than forwarded messages. A user clicking ‘forward’ is not auto-forwarding. Auto-forwarding happens when an outlook rule automatically forwards the mail. I’m not sure if you realize that from the content of your question?

Comment: By the way, these are the instructions on how to manage auto-forwarding in Office 365: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exovoice/2017/12/07/disable-automatic-forwarding-in-office-365-and-exchange-server-to-prevent-information-leakage/

Comment: Hi @Appleoddity - basically what I want to do is make it so users cannot setup forwarding in their OWA - which is what they are doing at the very top of that article that you posted under "Start forwarding" - I know it is different than a user forwarding their mail.

But when i create the transport rule just like it says in that article - it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: I’m not sure why, sorry. I can tell you that the article I linked to works great.

Comment: You have tried the option of creating a transport rule with the UI?

Comment: No. I performed the procedures in the article I linked to to remove the options from OWA, remove the forwarding rules that are already established, and block any future auto-forwarding rules.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://delapcyber.com/business-best-practices/two-methods-for-disabling-email-auto-forwarding-in-office-365/) reads:

> ...a **transport rule** in the ‘Exchange Online Admin Center‘. This approach allows for more granular control over how rules around auto-forwarding are applied. The main downside that must be considered is that this method **does not block users from leveraging the ‘Start/Stop Forwarding‘ function in Outlook Web Access (OWA)**.

**To block all types of forwarding including that which is initiated from OWA, the article mentions that a remote domain setting must be used instead of the transport rule approach**. If you prefer to use the mouse, you can follow the instructions in the article linked above to see how to make the configuration change in the GUI. If you're like me and prefer PowerShell, you can use Exchange Online PowerShell:

```
Set-RemoteDomain -Identity "*" -AutoForwardEnabled $false
```

My team helps clients with Office 365 security hardening assessments. Some team members feel that transport rules are less reliable because there is a greater chance of misconfiguration, and have reportedly seen environments where a transport rule is configured but not effective for one reason or another.

It's worth noting that if you take the remote domain approach suggested above, you need to also make sure that you do not have any other remote domains configured for auto-forwarding (i.e., other than the default remote domain, configured above, which applies to all domains [*] that do not have a more-specific remote domain scope configured). To determine if any remote domains are allowing automatic forwarding, you can run:

```
@(Get-RemoteDomain | ForEach-Object {if ($_.AutoForwardEnabled) {$_}})
```

Or if you're looking for a simple true/false (true = compliant; false = noncompliant):

```
@(Get-RemoteDomain | ForEach-Object {if ($_.AutoForwardEnabled) {$_}}).Count -eq 0
```

Any remote domain returned in the first of these two Get-RemoteDomain command samples can be remediated like:

```
Set-RemoteDomain -Identity "NameOfRemoteDomainEntry" -AutoForwardEnabled $false
```

or, to remediate *all remote domains* that do not have auto forwarding disabled:

```
Get-RemoteDomain | ForEach-Object {if ($_.AutoForwardEnabled) {$_}} | Set-RemoteDomain -AutoForwardEnabled $false
```